# PDF file seach and sending it through outlook

Tags: vba, excel

the below code search for the file in the mentioned folder and send the searched file through outlook. But I need to add few more conditions to it.

1. It should also mention the count of files found in the folder with the same name > duplicate files< and put the count in excel sheet next to the file name.
2. The below code only search in a respective folder and not in sub-folders. It should search in sub-folders as well inside the folder for the files.

---

```
Sub CheckandSend()

Dim obMail As Outlook.MailItem

Dim irow As Integer

Dim dpath As String

Dim pfile As String

`dpath = "xxxx"

`'' loop through all files and send mail

irow = 1


Do While Cells(irow, 1) <> Empty

 '' get file name in column A

pfile = Dir(dpath & "\*" & Cells(irow, 1) & "*")

 '' check file exist and pdf file 

If pfile <> "" And Right(pfile, 3) = "pdf" 

Then

Set obMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  With obMail
    .To = "xxx@domain.com"
    .Subject = "123"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
    .Body = "123"
    .Attachments.Add (dpath & "\" & pfile)
    .Send

 End With

 End If

 irow = irow + 1

Loop

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code to this, which will search the directory (and sub-directories) for all PDF files using Windows scripting and then send each file found.

This handles your second issue, but I don't understand your first issue as:

a) How can you have identically named files in the same folder?
b) You haven't showed what you have tried yourself so far.

```
Sub SO()

Const masterFolder As String = "C:\Users\Macro Man\Files"
Dim files, file

files = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & masterFolder & "\*.pdf"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")

For Each file In files
    With Outlook.CreateItem(0)
        .To = "xxx@domain.com"
        .Subject = "123"
        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
        .Body = "123"
        .Attachments.Add CStr(file)
        .Send
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank u for it and for the first  query I mean there can be duplicate  files in multiple folder so I want the count of the final search of the similar files with same names.

Comment: Also the above code send all the pdf files in the directory. I want to send  only the files with names mentioned in the column A of the sheet one after the other after searching the files in the directory.

Comment: You need to give more information in your question then

Comment: Sorry If I missed out explaining clearly. What changes should i make now for both the queries.

Comment: I have been still trying for both the issues but couldn't find a code to resolve it.